# Wi-Fi adapters supporting monitor mode with Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi

I have a Raspberry Pi and I want to use it for penetration testing of Wi-Fi networks. I want to buy a Wi-Fi USB adapter for my Raspberry however I don't know which one. I have read a list of Raspberry Pi supported Wi-Fi adapters however I don't know if these support monitor mode and packet injection.

How can I know if a Wi-Fi adapter supports monitor mode and packet injection?
Are all adapters supported by Kali supported by Raspberry running Kali?
And do you have any adapter suggestions?

Comment: This is off topic here - I'm checking with two of our sister sites to see if we can migrate it over, either to the raspberry pi stack exchange, or to unix&linux. Give me a few minutes. We'll need to remove the last sentence though, as we don't do shopping recommendations.

Comment: the Tenda W311M which shows as 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter worked well for me in monitor mode to test WEP and WPA2 installations

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping choices. any usb wifi adapter that supports monitor mode under Linux will support the same mode on RPi.

Answer (score 3):

Look for usb wifi adapters with the following chipsets:

1. Atheros AR9271
2. Ralink RT3070
3. Realtek RTL8187L

Hope this helps.

Comment: any 5ghz ones?  I need to not interfere with my 2.4ghz rc radio